# Add generated subproject configure file to main project in CMake

Tags: lua, cmake, config

I am trying to compile my application using CMake, and I need to compile Lua with it for various reasons. My current setup is as follows:

`project/
  CMakeLists.txt
  ...
  libs/
     CMakeLists.txt
     ...
     lua/
        CMakeLists.txt
        ...`

I am using LuaDist as it already provides a CMake build system for lua. The problem comes when I try to include `lua.h` from my project, as it requires `luaconfig.h` which is generated by the Lua subproject and output to its binary directory, not source directory.

In my main project I do something like this:

`include_directories(libs/lua/src/ etc...)`

How can I also include generated files from subprojects in my main project?

Comment: checkout ExternalProject from cmake if you need to run `configure` and `make` on external projects.

Comment: I don't really need to run nor `configure` nor `make` on any of the imported libraries, as they all ship with CMake build configurations. The problem is that Lua creates a header file on compilation, and that is copied to the build directory and not added to the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're including lua directly via an `add_subdirectory` call, you can also use `include_directories(${lua_BINARY_DIR})` (assuming there's a `project(lua)` command in lua's CMakeLists.txt file). The name of the variable may be something else if the project command is different, or you may need multiple additional include_directories, depending on where the header files you need are ... but this should get you started.

Comment: This worked, thank! For future reference though, you might want to edit `${lua_BINARY_DIRECTORY}` into `${lua_BINARY_DIR}`!

Comment: Is this still correct in 2021?  I'm using more or less this exact use case and the includes are not being found / added to my compile line...

Comment: I think it's still correct. What version of CMake are you using? What value are you passing to include_directories? Maybe a ```message("lua_BINARY_DIR='${lua_BINARY_DIR}'")``` will help you figure out why it's not working. Remember: CMake variable names are case sensitive, and non-existent vars will silently evaluate to the empty string.